# How to update a Listbox's Values using ViewData

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have a ViewData that is being used to generate a List, upon selecting an item, that items info will be displayed in textboxes for viewing and editing. Upon clicking the save button, it saves but the listbox isn't being updated, how can update this listbox since I'm using a viewdata?

```
   @Html.ListBox("ListBoxName", new SelectList((IEnumerable<Epic>)ViewData["selectedestimate"], "Id", "Name", "EstimatedTime"), new {@class = "ListBoxClass", @style = "height: 325px;"})

   <button id="EpicSaveId" type="submit" class="btn" onclick="SaveEpicInfo((document.getElementById('EpicNameID').value), (document.getElementById('EpicTimeId').value), (document.getElementById('EpicDescriptionID').value))">
```

Upon Clicking Save Button: (Javascript)

```
        function SaveEpicInfo(name, time, description) {
    $.get('@Url.Action("SaveEditEpic", "Estimate")', { id: eid, epicname: name, epictime: time, epicdescription: description }, function (result) {
        alert(result);

    });

}
```

Controller:

```
     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult SaveEditEpic(int id, string epicname, double epictime, string epicdescription)
    {
        var epic = epicRepository.Select().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
        if (epic != null)
        {
            epic.Name = epicname;
            epic.EstimatedTime = epictime;
            epic.EpicDescription = epicdescription;
            //ViewData["selectedestimate"] = epicRepository.Select().Where(x => x.EstimateId.Equals(ActiveEstimateId)).ToList();
            return Json("Epic Saved", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("Error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to iterate through those select arrays and look for the option with selected = true and then store that value.

Comment: Right..but how do I access that. How do I call the select arrays. In another javascript I had I had something like    $(".ListBoxClass").click(function (event) {
            var selectedid = $(this).find("option:selected").val();      This just returns one value though.

Comment: Set an id on the selectlist. This will correlate with the `<select>` element on the DOM. Select the `<select>` element by id (or jQuery equiv) and then get its options by using the `.options[]` call on the `<select>` element. http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=get+options+javascript+from+select